# CSS Puzzle - Classed Link Span won't change color on hover

Tags: html, css

I have some CSS that allows my menu items to load one after the other.  Each link is located within a nice span.  On the cover page, the span is black and on hover turns a rich blue.  On the other pages, the links are grey but the hover isn't working.  No color change.

The hover code wasn't touched with the exception of the introduction of a class, so I'm not sure why it isn't working.   the codes are:

HTML:

```
<!-- navigation -->

    <nav id="navpage">

    <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="ALT" width="130" height="130" /></a>
    <ul class="navpage-links">
       <li class="navpage-link work"><a href="portfolio.html">My Work</a></li>
       <li class="navpage-link about"><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
       <li class="navpage-link contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
       <li class="navpage-link blog"><a href="Link">The Blog</a></li>
    </ul>

    </nav>
<!-- close navigation -->
```

The Original CSS that is working on hover:

```
.nav-link a, .nav-link span.link-placeholder {
    display: block;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.11em;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-link.about a.hover {
    background-color: #0089d2;
}
```

The Applicable CSS that ISN"T working:

```
.navpage-link a, .navpage-link span.link-placeholder {
    display: block;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.5);
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.4);
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.11em;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
}

.navpage-link.about a.hover {
    background-color: #0089d2;
}
```

As you can see I didn't change the code except for the adjustment for the class... what did I miss?

Comment: I think you want `a:hover` not `a.hover`.  Although that's in both so not sure how the first one was working, unless there was a script to add a class `hover`.

Comment: Christ!  Its always something ridiculously simple!  Thank you, you are a lifesaver.  I was LOSING it.  There was infact a script adding a class, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are addressing to the wrong `child-class` in the CSS, that isn't working....you have to assign it to the parent class => `navpage-links` instead of `navpage-link`!!

<kbd>[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q2mEh/)</kbd>

**This is the error :**

```
.navpage-link.about a.hover {
  /*        ^^ a space and "s" is missing here */
    background-color: #0089d2;
}
```

change it to :

```
.navpage-links .about a.hover {
      /*      ^^ notice here */
        background-color: #0089d2;
    }
```